# Get access of google sheets of other account

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

Is it possible to access the google sheet of other account like that of my colleague based on my service account?
I am trying to automate google sheets with Python but most of my sheets are not in one account but on other accounts. I was wondering if I could interact with all of them based on one service account? I am using gspread library for my automation.

Answer (score 0):

- You can access the Google Spreadsheet(s) of your colleague if they have been shared with you or are all contained in a folder that has been shared with you. Depending on what you would like to do, most likely you need an editor permission.
- In the same way, your service account can access the Google Spreadsheet(s) of your colleague if they have been shared with  or are all contained in a folder that has been shared with your service account.